# Android Material 3 TopAppBar custom color theme

Tags: android, material-design, android-view, material3

## Goal

Create an ActionBar with a custom color theme differing from the color theme applied by the global theme + preserve elevation coloring if content is scrolled

## Minimal Working Example

*(Colors and theme were extracted from the Material Theme Builder)*

- on Android Studio Electric Eel 2022.1.1 Patch 2 `New -> New Project-> Basic Activity (Material3)`
- Name project `App`
- add following full Material 3 color set under `values -> colors.xml`

```xml
<!-- colors.xml -->


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="seed">#0031b4</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_primary">#3252D0</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_onPrimary">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_primaryContainer">#DDE1FF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_onPrimaryContainer">#001356</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_secondary">#246D00</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_onSecondary">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_secondaryContainer">#87FD55</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_onSecondaryContainer">#062100</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_tertiary">#00677E</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_onTertiary">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_tertiaryContainer">#B5EBFF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_onTertiaryContainer">#001F28</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_error">#BA1A1A</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_errorContainer">#FFDAD6</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_onError">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_onErrorContainer">#410002</color>

    <color name="md_theme_light_background">#FEFBFF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_onBackground">#1B1B1F</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_surface">#FEFBFF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_onSurface">#1B1B1F</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_surfaceVariant">#E2E1EC</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_onSurfaceVariant">#45464F</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_outline">#767680</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_inverseOnSurface">#F3F0F4</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_inverseSurface">#303034</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_inversePrimary">#B9C3FF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_shadow">#000000</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_surfaceTint">#3252D0</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_outlineVariant">#C6C5D0</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_scrim">#000000</color>

    <!-- Dark theme colors -->
    <color name="md_theme_dark_primary">#B9C3FF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_onPrimary">#002388</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_primaryContainer">#0C37B8</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_onPrimaryContainer">#DDE1FF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_secondary">#6BE03A</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_onSecondary">#0F3900</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_secondaryContainer">#195200</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_onSecondaryContainer">#87FD55</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_tertiary">#5BD5FA</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_onTertiary">#003543</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_tertiaryContainer">#004E60</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_onTertiaryContainer">#B5EBFF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_error">#FFB4AB</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_errorContainer">#93000A</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_onError">#690005</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_onErrorContainer">#FFDAD6</color>

    <color name="md_theme_dark_background">#1B1B1F</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_onBackground">#E4E1E6</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_surface">#1B1B1F</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_onSurface">#E4E1E6</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_surfaceVariant">#45464F</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_onSurfaceVariant">#C6C5D0</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_outline">#90909A</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_inverseOnSurface">#1B1B1F</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_inverseSurface">#E4E1E6</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_inversePrimary">#3252D0</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_shadow">#000000</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_surfaceTint">#B9C3FF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_outlineVariant">#45464F</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_scrim">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

- apply following theme under `values -> themes -> themes.xml`

```xml
<!-- themes.xml -->


<resources>
    <style name="Base.Theme.App" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/md_theme_light_primary</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/md_theme_light_onPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryContainer">@color/md_theme_light_primaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimaryContainer">@color/md_theme_light_onPrimaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/md_theme_light_secondary</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/md_theme_light_onSecondary</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryContainer">@color/md_theme_light_secondaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondaryContainer">@color/md_theme_light_onSecondaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorTertiary">@color/md_theme_light_tertiary</item>
        <item name="colorOnTertiary">@color/md_theme_light_onTertiary</item>
        <item name="colorTertiaryContainer">@color/md_theme_light_tertiaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorOnTertiaryContainer">@color/md_theme_light_onTertiaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorError">@color/md_theme_light_error</item>
        <item name="colorErrorContainer">@color/md_theme_light_errorContainer</item>
        <item name="colorOnError">@color/md_theme_light_onError</item>
        <item name="colorOnErrorContainer">@color/md_theme_light_onErrorContainer</item>

        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/md_theme_light_background</item>
        <item name="colorOnBackground">@color/md_theme_light_onBackground</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/md_theme_light_surface</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/md_theme_light_onSurface</item>
        <item name="colorSurfaceVariant">@color/md_theme_light_surfaceVariant</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurfaceVariant">@color/md_theme_light_onSurfaceVariant</item>
        <item name="colorOutline">@color/md_theme_light_outline</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurfaceInverse">@color/md_theme_light_inverseOnSurface</item>
        <item name="colorSurfaceInverse">@color/md_theme_light_inverseSurface</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryInverse">@color/md_theme_light_inversePrimary</item>

    </style>


    <style name="Theme.App" parent="Base.Theme.App">

    </style>

</resources>
```

- Run on a Pixel 4a Emulator with API33 Level
- Observe TopAppBar color white

[image]

and bluish on scroll

[image]

## Problem

Now I want to change the TopAppBar color (i.e. the complete area that gets the bluish color if scrolled) to my `colorPrimary` AND keep the scroll effect (drawing a slightly darker color for the bar). According to [material.io](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TopAppBar.md#container-attributes) the color used by the TopAppBar is  `onSurface` which is elevated to `3dp` on scroll. My thinking was to re-set `onSurface` according to [theming guide](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TopAppBar.md#theming-the-top-app-bar).

Since the emulator runs API33 I go to already existing `values -> themes-v29 -> themes.xml` and try to set it like so:

```xml
<!-- themes.xml(v29) -->


<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <style name="Theme.App" parent="Base.Theme.App">
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">?attr/isLightTheme</item>



       <!-- delegate style definition to a custom style to re-set <onSurface> -->
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.App.Toolbar</item>

    </style>

    <!-- custom style definition -->
    <style name="Widget.App.Toolbar" parent="Widget.Material3.Toolbar">
        <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.Toolbar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeOverlay.App.Toolbar" parent="">
        <item name="colorSurface">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

but nothing changes.

I'm new to android so don't assume to much competence ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and it took me some time finding an answer to this. Turns out `AppBarLayout` has background set to `MaterialDrawableShape`, which determines the toolbar color. You can set the color to your own using `public void setTintList(@Nullable ColorStateList tintList)` method of `MaterialDrawableShape`.

Example in kotlin:

```kotlin
(appBarLayout.background as? MaterialShapeDrawable)?.let {
    val states = arrayOf(
        intArrayOf(R.attr.state_lifted),  // lifted (scrolled) state
        intArrayOf(-R.attr.state_lifted), // unlifted state
    )

    val colors = intArrayOf(
        Color.RED,          //Color for lifted state
        Color.TRANSPARENT,  //Color for unlifted state
    )
    it.tintList = ColorStateList(states, colors)
}
```

To avoid pasting this piece of code in every Activity I decided to extend `AppBarLayout` like this:

```kotlin
class CustomColorAppBar @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = com.google.android.material.R.attr.appBarLayoutStyle
) : AppBarLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    init {
        (background as? MaterialShapeDrawable)?.let {
            val states = arrayOf(
                intArrayOf(R.attr.state_lifted),
                intArrayOf(-R.attr.state_lifted),
            )
            val colors = intArrayOf(
                context.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary),
                Color.TRANSPARENT,
            )
            it.tintList = ColorStateList(states, colors)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Have you also found a working no-code solution, i.e. setting values in the xml of the default views?